# Float prints a large, weird value

Tags: c++, pointers, cocos2d-x

So, I create a `State` class. In that `State` class's create function, it creates a `StateVisual` class by calling the `StateVisual` class's create function, passing itself as a parameter. (The parameter is a reference so that there is no copying). The `StateVisual` then sets the parameter (The `State` Instance), as it's parent variable, which is a pointer of a State type.

In the `StateVisual`'s create function, everything works fine. However, when you get to it's update method, and try to print it's parent size, it prints some weird value.

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

#include "cocos2d.h"
class StateVisual;



class State {
public:

    State();
    ~State();
    static State create();
    StateVisual *visual;
    float size;
    void setSize(float);
    void update(float);
private:
    cocos2d::Scheduler* _scheduler;


};

#endif
```

`StateVisual.cpp`

```
#ifndef STATE_VIS_H
#define STATE_VIS_H



#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "State.h"


class StateVisual : public cocos2d::Sprite {

public:

    StateVisual();
    ~StateVisual();

    // create a visual
    State* parent;
    static StateVisual* create(State& parent);
    cocos2d::Label* label;
    void setSize(float);
    void update(float);




private:
    bool _activated;
    float _size;


};

#endif
```

`State.cpp`

```
#include "State.h"
#include "GameScene.h"


State::State() : size(0) {
    CCLOG("Created");
}

State::~State() {

}

void State::setSize(float newSize) {
    size = newSize;
    CCLOG("%f, %f", newSize, size);
}

void State::update(float dt) {

}

State State::create() {
    State state;
    state.visual = StateVisual::create(state);
    cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE ss;
    return state;
}
```

`StateVisual.cpp`

```
#include "StateVisual.h"
#include "GameScene.h"

using namespace cocos2d;


StateVisual::StateVisual() : parent(nullptr) {
    CCLOG("New STATE VISUAL!");
}
StateVisual::~StateVisual() {

}
void StateVisual::setSize(float size) {
    setContentSize(Size(size, size));
    if (size > 30) {
        label->setSystemFontSize(size*.1);
        label->setOpacity(255);
    }
    else {
        label->setOpacity(0);
    }
}

void StateVisual::update(float dt) {
    cocos2d::MathUtil::smooth(&_size, parent->size, dt, .2);
    setSize(_size);
    CCLOG("%f, %f", _size, (*this->parent).size);
}

StateVisual* StateVisual::create(State &parent) {

    StateVisual* visual(new StateVisual());

    if (visual->initWithFile("Circle.png"))
    {
        visual->setSize(200);
        visual->_size = 200;

        visual->parent = &parent;
        visual->parent->setSize(20);
        CCLOG("PARENT SIZE: %f", visual->parent->size);

        visual->autorelease();
        visual->scheduleUpdate();
        return visual;
    }

    CC_SAFE_DELETE(visual);
    return NULL;
}
```

It outputs:

```
Created
New STATE VISUAL!
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at /cc_2x2_white_image. Possible 
missing file.
20.000000, 20.000000
PARENT SIZE: 20.000000
500.000000, 500.000000
cocos2d: QuadCommand: resizing index size from [-1] to [2560]

168.058044, -107374176.000000  <-- Those are the weird values it prints
155.130508, -107374176.000000

The program '[1464] State.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What is the type of `size`?

Comment: It really doesnt help debugging this code that you have 3 classes with a member named `setSize`

Comment: And what is `_size`?

Comment: You have left out crucial information, particularly the header files that define the classes that have a `setSize()` member function.   Having multiple member functions and data members, all with similar names, suggests you have gotten yourself confused (e.g. expecting functionality that is in one class to be in another, when it isn't).   Therefore I have voted to close the question as unclear.   You need to clean up your code and, if you expect help on SO, provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
State State::create() {
    State state;
    state.visual = StateVisual::create(state);
    cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE ss;
    return state;
}
```

At the end of this function the local object state is destroyed a copy ois made (or moved to a new object). Which means any pointer to the address &state is invalid after the end of `State::create`

```
visual->parent = &parent; // parent = state object on stack
```

Because of this line `visual->parent` is now dangling.
Those weird values are the random content of you thread stack...

What you should do is use shared pointers for state\parent.

Answer (score 5):

`0xCCCCCCCC`, a typical value used to fill uninitialized memory in Debug builds, interpreted as a 32-bit float, equals `-107374176.000000`. You're printing an uninitialized `float` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
void StateVisual::update(float dt) {
cocos2d::MathUtil::smooth(&_size, parent->size, dt, .2);
setSize(_size);
CCLOG("%f, %f", _size, (*this->parent).size);
```

1. Why do you use `parent->size` in 1 row of function and `(*this->parent).size` in third?
2. Why don't you use getters and setters?
3. Why haven't you shown header files?
4. Why haven't you prepared minimal example (like just parent-child logic and sizes without labels, positions etc.?
5. What is this suposed to do? `StateVisual* visual(new StateVisual());`
   If `visual` is automatic variable, i think it should look loke `StateVisual visual(new StateVisual());` otherwise shouldn't it be `StateVisual* visual = new StateVisual(new StateVisual());` Also are you sure you want to pass new StateVisual object into constructor of StateVisual?

Comment: 1. That is the result of me doing different things to see what went wrong 2. Why should I, does it change something, I don't know. 3. I highly doubt those would change anything, especially for this type of problem. Seems to be a cpp related issue. 4. For this type of issue, which I know little about, how will I know what to remove and to keep? In your third question, you want me to include even the things I doubt would change much, but here you want to remove the things I doubt would change much and keep it minimal? 5. In cocos2d I think it encourages pointers for classes

Comment: You should have used getter and add breakpoint in that getter with your debugger and that would probably tell you what is going on.

Comment: I can't do that with a simple assignment statement?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you can look into disassembly for debugging if you are that pro h4xx0r. 
But you asked for help with debugging on SO, so I've shared what are best practices.
I believe that calling getter method instead of using assignment on variable would trigger assert, at least with binary compiled in debug, but this depends on your compiler (I think calling method on dangling pointer is undefined behaviour)